# Printing Function Output to Syslog?

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I want to make it so that the "stdout" and "stderr" output from "check_call()" is sent to Syslog.  Is this possible?

Code:

```
def command(cmd, err=None, ifexit=False):
    try:
        check_call(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=null, stderr=null)

    except CalledProcessError:
        if err != None:
            print err

        if ifexit == True:
            exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but i think you would need to use `Popen` instead of `check_call`, and send the process' `stdout` and `stderr` to a properly configured logger.
Such a logger would use `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler` to send messages to your syslog server. Here is a short example of how such a logger could be created:

```
import logging

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger('myApplication')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

And here is an example of how you could replace `check_call` with `Popen` and send the data to the logger:

```
process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
# Popen.wait() waits for the command to complete and 
# returns the command's return code
if process.wait() != 0:
    print "AN ERROR OCCURED"
logger.error(process.stderr)
logger.info(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get Popen to tell me the if the command executed successfully?

Comment: @Kevin just check the [`process.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.returncode) value or use the `process.wait()` method. I've updated my answer to wait for the command to complete and check if it succesded.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this in 2017 so I thought it might be good to go ahead and update this for Python 3 as the solution needs slight modification.  In order to be able to utilize the `SysLogHandler` in Python 3, you will have to adjust the code as follows:

```
 import logging
 import logging.handlers as handlers

 handler = handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log')
 logger = logging.getLogger('myApplication')
 logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
 logger.addHandler(handler)
```

As detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler), `SysLogHandler` class

> Returns a new instance of the SysLogHandler class intended to communicate with a remote Unix machine whose address is given by address in the form of a (host, port) tuple. If address is not specified, ('localhost', 514) is used. The address is used to open a socket. An alternative to providing a (host, port) tuple is providing an address as a string, for example ‘/dev/log’. In this case, a Unix domain socket is used to send the message to the syslog.